# Works through REPL but fails when ran from command line : AttributeError: module 'talib' has no attribute 'MA'

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to use the library `TA-Lib`, I installed it and the following code works when I feed it line by line to a python shell :

```
import numpy
import talib
from numpy import genfromtxt

price = genfromtxt( "/home/volt/projects/data/history.csv")
length = len(price)
MA5 = talib.MA(price, 5)
MA100 = talib.MA(price, 100)
```

but when I run the whole script from bash it says :

```
python talib.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talib.py", line 2, in <module>
    import talib
  File "/home/volt/projects/technical_analysis/talib.py", line 7, in <module>
    MA5 = talib.MA(price, 5)
AttributeError: module 'talib' has no attribute 'MA'
```

Any idea how this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are working with a script whose name is `talib`, which itself imports the module `talib`. You have a doublon in your namespace. I mean, you do

```
#talib.py
import talib
```

Since python checks for module in the working directory before searching on the path, `talib.py` actually imports itself !

Rename your working script, e.g. `mytalib.py`, and do not forget to remove the `talib.pyc` generated in your working directory.

---

To clearly figure this out, create a script named `myscript.py`, with the following content

```
print('hello')
import myscript
```

Execute this script. It will print `"hello"` twice.

Comment: incredible, I wasn't aware of this, thank you for your help